# Cannot connect to server in SQL Server Management Studio after installing a new SSD

Tags: ssms, solid-state-drive

I've just installed an SSD to my laptop. As a result most of my programs won't run unless I do a few tricks to make it reusable, the worst case is to uninstall and re-install it.

Now it's for SQL Server Management Studio 2019, I can access the "Connect to server" interface as the old server I used before installing SSD has disappeared. I just don't know how to connect to it while I don't really want to uninstall and reinstall as SSMS tooks a long time to install.

Is there any way I can connect to my old server? or at least if there's none, how can I backup my old sql script and .bak files to use after I install a new SSMS?

[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuNpf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to give only your machine name. Like if it is Your machine name/serverInstance so simply give it only your machine name then try to login.

Explanation why this trick works:-

Here " https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15 "
Microsoft writes "An instance is either the default instance or a named instance. The default instance name is MSSQLSERVER. It does not require a client to specify the name of the instance to make a connection."

So if you created default instance (MSSQLSERVER) or named instance with name MSSQLSERVER you then should not add the instance name but just use the server's name (your machine name).